# Moving domain to Shopify, but still need access to Magento store

Tags: magento2

I am moving my domain to a Shopify store. But I still need access to the Magento Backend to see orders and so on.

How do i do that I Magento?

Have tried to just move It to Shopify, but then the: www.domian/admin path don't work.

Help!

Magento ver. 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom admin url, to do that go to:

> Store > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Admin Base URL

And set a subdomain for example: https://admin.domain.com

[image]